# iphone - App crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS or some other weird error when setting value to a NSManagedObject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, core-data

OK, so this code below sometimes crashes on the line below "//bug!!"

The error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS and no Zombies are responsible as far as I know.
The app still crashes on the same line even if I switch up the 2 lines inside the for-loop.

course is a Course, which is a NSManagedObject, and contains many Card objects.
What I'm trying to do is simply set a couple of property values in every Card in course.

The strange thing is that when I try to NSLog inside the loop, the bug never appeared again.
Then, some time after I comment out the NSLog, the bug appears.

Also, this function is called in a separate thread by a MBProgressHUD, which displays a spinner and message.
cardView is a subclass of UIViewController

```
- (void)resetLearningData {

// get an array of cards
NSMutableArray *cards = [[course.card allObjects] mutableCopy];

NSDate  *newDate = [[NSDate date] copy];
NSNumber *newNum = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] copy];
int n = [cards count];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Card *c = (Card *)[cards objectAtIndex:i];

    // attempting to solve bug below
    //NSLog(@"Setting card #%d", i); // if this line is uncommented, bug doesn't appear.
    // bug!!!!! sometimes EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    [c setNum_rep:newNum];
    [c setNext_rep:newDate];
}
[cards release];
[newDate release];
[newNum release];

// Write to Disk
NSError *error = nil;
if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    [self showMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error resetting learning data! \n%@", [error userInfo]]];
}

[cardView reloadCourse];
[cardView reloadInterface];
}
```

Typical backtrace is this:

```
#0  0x010efa04 in __CFBasicHashAddValue ()
#1  0x010ef866 in CFBasicHashAddValue ()
#2  0x0110b472 in CFSetAddValue ()
#3  0x00f366d2 in _PFFastMOCObjectWillChange ()
#4  0x00f364aa in _PF_ManagedObject_WillChangeValueForKeyIndex ()
#5  0x00f362f5 in _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core ()
#6  0x00f43da7 in _svfk_2 ()
#7  0x00007410 in -[CourseToolTableViewController resetLearningData] (self=0x4d69d00, _cmd=0x20144) at /Users/admin/Documents/Random15/Classes/../CourseToolTableViewController.m:181
#8  0x0000b491 in -[MBProgressHUD launchExecution] (self=0x59c96a0, _cmd=0x20b08) at /Users/admin/Documents/Random15/Classes/MBProgressHUD.m:474
#9  0x00270d4c in -[NSThread main] ()
#10 0x00270cd8 in __NSThread__main__ ()
#11 0x940b985d in _pthread_start ()
#12 0x940b96e2 in thread_start ()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code above and my guess would be that you are sharing the same NSManagedObjectContext and/or NSManagedObjects between the two threads which is a no no with Coredata.

You will need to create a separate managed object context for your background thread, make additions/changes to your managed objects within that context and then pass objectIDs around between the two contexts.

Here's a good reference from Apple http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html

Answer (score 0):

Well as i know EXC_BAD_ACCESS generally comes due to early release of an object,Try to put the breakpoints and debug then to see where the app is crashing.And moreover using Copy property makes the object immutable.
Hope someone else can help you more.
But do debugging yourself that will  also help you in the future.....

Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

ewon - It appears that when you change an attribute (in my case also an NSNumber) that is marked as Indexed - this happens when you change the attribute value

In my case, I inserted a new entity with an ID attribute of ZERO, and later update the entity when I know the "ID" and I get the same error.

Try removing the Indexed checkmark on the Attribute ?

(Tried to post an image of the Indexed check option, but I can't - No reputation :-)

The clue is the error located in "_PF_ManagedObject_WillChangeValueForKeyIndex"

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue as well and it turned out that I the messaged object was observing a managed object and got deallocated before properly unobserving it.